# WooCommerce - 500k Jump in Order Number?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, mysql

We run a WooCommerce site and last week noticed that our order numbers increased dramatically by 500,000 (ex. 8088 to 508098). This was alarming to our fulfillment team.

I understand that WooCommerce order numbers are created from the wp_posts ID. It's perfectly normal for us to see small skips (5-20) in the order numbers because the table includes other post types and there are usually other records being created between shop orders.

I checked the wp_posts table and sure enough, there is a huge jump in the ID field.
I also noticed that the ID in wp_users jumped by 1000 (ex. 446 to 1447).

[image]

I retraced my steps to try and note any recent changes I had made prior to noticing the issue:

- Some small edits on a few pages
- Changed page status from published to draft on several pages
- Setup some 301 Redirects
- Created a new staging instance on our webhost

My suspicion is that part of the process our host uses when creating a staging instance is to "provision" ID numbers so that later if the staging site is merged with the live site, there are not duplicate ID numbers.

To test my theory, I created a 2nd staging instance and sure enough, the ID's on the live site jumped up another 500,000.

I chatted at length with hosting support and they insist the staging sites are not the cause. They claim that the issue is being caused by a plugin, although they can't tell me which plugin or how/why.

Has anyone else experienced massive jumps in order/ID numbers before? Is it possible this is a plugin issue? How can I confirm the cause?
Thanks!

Comment: Products import, new variadions and general posts creation could cause that. Some one could have manualy added a row to the DB with a high ID.This should not worry one bit, your site will run the same no problem. But if that is a problem logistecly you could create a custom meta field and update it every time a new order is created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved: After more testing and chatting with hosting support (WPX.net), they finally confirmed the issue was with their staging site creation process.

"From here on we will try to fix the whole ID change or at least put a big warning message."